# DateTime parameter when calling stored function from java code

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I call stored function with such signature:

> FUNCTION ADDDAYS (city VARCHAR2,
>   startDate DATE, numDays INTEGER)

from java code:

```
        JdbcTemplate jt = getJdbcTemplate();
        Object o = jt.execute("{? = call ADDDAYS(?, ?, ?)}", new CallableStatementCallback() {
            public Object doInCallableStatement(CallableStatement stmt) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
                 stmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.DATE);
                stmt.setString(2, city);
                stmt.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(startDate.getTime()));
                stmt.setInt(4, daysNum);
                stmt.execute();
                return new Date(stmt.getDate(1).getTime());
            }

        });
```

when I pass startDate with time return value contais 00:00 as time (stored procedure doesn't cut time part, i checked it with direct calls from sql editor).
So looks like time part is removed in sending to/receiving form Oracle.
is it possible to fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: I hope you realizing that an `ADDDAYS` function is reinventing the wheel; adding an number to an Oracle `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` adds that number of days (or fractions thereof) to it.

Comment: It is not just adding of N days to specified date, it uses business days calendars for different cities. Why whould I pass city parameter to this function if I just need to add N days to current date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java.sql.Date` is meant to store only date without time information.
You should use `java.sql.Timestamp`, `setTimestamp` and `getTimestamp` to handle date & time informations.
Look also at `java.sql.Time` and `set/getTime` if you need only time information.